# How to recycle views in a LinearLayout, to avoid multiple calls to findViewById()?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, optimization

I want to dynamically add a list of items inflated from layout XMLs to a `LinearLayout` within a `ScrollView`. This involves calling `findViewById` numerous times for each item, which I have been told is very expensive. How can I recycle my views to avoid this?

I would use a `ListView`, except each item can have any number of content and comment elements within it and I have been told in [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) that `ListView`s should not be overcomplicated.

Here is my code for the relevant method:

```
private void addQuotes(NodeList quoteNodeList){

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for(int i = 0; i < quoteNodeList.getLength(); i++){

        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Adding quote number " + i);

        Node quoteNode = quoteNodeList.item(i);
        // Inflate view to hold multiple content items, single additional content TextView, and multiple comment items
        LinearLayout quote = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.quote, null);
        LinearLayout contentList = (LinearLayout) quote.findViewById(R.id.dialog_list);
        TextView additionalContent = (TextView) quote.findViewById(R.id.additional_content);
        LinearLayout commentList = (LinearLayout) quote.findViewById(R.id.comment_list);

        // Get data for content items and add to contentList
        NodeList contentNodeList =
                XmlUtilities.getChildWithTagName(quoteNode, NetworkHelper.XML_TAG_QUOTE_CONTENT).getChildNodes();
        for(int contentIndex = 0; contentIndex < contentNodeList.getLength(); contentIndex++){

            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Adding content number " + contentIndex + " to quote number " + i);

            Node contentItemNode = contentNodeList.item(contentIndex);
            // Inflate view to hold name and dialog TextViews
            LinearLayout contentItem = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_item, null);
            TextView nameView = (TextView) contentItem.findViewById(R.id.speaker);
            TextView dialogView = (TextView) contentItem.findViewById(R.id.dialog);
            // Get data and insert into views
            String nameString = XmlUtilities.getChildTextValue(contentItemNode, NetworkHelper.XML_TAG_QUOTE_CONTENT_ITEM_NAME);
            String dialogString = XmlUtilities.getChildTextValue(contentItemNode, NetworkHelper.XML_TAG_QUOTE_CONTENT_ITEM_DIALOG);
            nameView.setText(nameString + ":");
            dialogView.setText("\"" + dialogString + "\"");
            // Add to parent view
            contentList.addView(contentItem);
        }

        // Get additional content data and add
        String additionalContentString = XmlUtilities.getChildTextValue(
                quoteNode, NetworkHelper.XML_TAG_QUOTE_ADDITIONAL_CONTENT);
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "additionalContentString: " + additionalContentString);
        additionalContent.setText(additionalContentString);

        // TODO: Get comment data and add

        // Add everything to ScrollView
        mQuoteList.addView(quote);
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "additionalContent: " + additionalContent.getText());

    }
```

The parameter `quoteNodeList` is an `org.w3c.dom.NodeList`.
`XmlUtilities` is a helper class I wrote myself but the methods should be self explanatory.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This involves calling findViewById numerous times for each item, which I have been told is very expensive.

Not nearly as expensive as the inflation itself. If you have 10,000 comments, you will inflate 10,000 rows, putting you at risk of running out of heap space and/or freezing your UI entirely too long.

> How can I recycle my views to avoid this?

You can't, given your structure.

> I would use a ListView, except each item can have any number of content and comment elements within it and I have been told in Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView that ListViews should not be overcomplicated.

Since your proposed solution will be significantly more "overcomplicated" -- by two or three orders of magnitude -- use a `ListView`.

Comment: This is a strong answer as usual, but it doesn't address: "except each item can have any number of content and comment elements within it". Judging from the nested loop perhaps an [`ExpandableListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) is a better choice?

Comment: @Sam: "but it doesn't address: "except each item can have any number of content and comment elements within it"" -- that is simply a matter of using the proper row layout for the position, populating it accordingly, and overriding `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` in your `Adapter`. "Judging from the nested loop perhaps an ExpandableListView is a better choice?" -- that has a fairly specific UI. If that's the UI you want, definitely go for it.